# Concurrent Dictionary multiple writes

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency

Im wondering, does C# ConcurrentDictionary support multiple simultaneous writes? Or do all writes serialize? I know it is optimized for reading but what about writting? Can i expect good performance with multiple threads constantly writting to the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with a normal dictionary the writes are "bucketed" in to groups, those buckets are then grouped together in locking groups. the number of locking groups is known as the dictionary's "Concurrency Level". By default the concurrency level is equal to 4 times the result of [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx), however you can override it with [several](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287173.aspx) [of its](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267257.aspx) [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287151.aspx).

To figure out if the two writes are going to hit the same lock it uses the private method `GetBucketAndLockNo` to figure which hash bucket and which lock to use.

```
//Code generated via ILSpy from .NET 4.0
private void GetBucketAndLockNo(int hashcode, out int bucketNo, out int lockNo, int bucketCount, int lockCount)
{
    bucketNo = (hashcode & 0x7FFFFFFF) % bucketCount;
    lockNo = bucketNo % lockCount;
}
```

So to answer your original question "Can i expect good performance with multiple threads constantly writing to the dictionary?" the answer really depends on how well distributed the hash is and if you will be constantly inserting records that will fall in to the same lock grouping. There is no way to find out without testing it with real world data and seeing if it is performant enough.

Also note, [there where performance improvements made to ConcurrentDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/08/10235147.aspx) in .NET 4.5 so if you are using .NET 4.0 vs 4.5 could change your results. For example if you do not specify the number of locks in the constructor to use it will dynamically add more locks as the dictionary grows.